# How can I solve this differential equations?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a calculus exam on tuesday and this two questions were asked last year!
But I have a problem with integrating to obtain the factor:
[image]

If is there anything you don't understand, just say it!

Comment: simplify the fraction! It's equal to $1/y$..

Comment: In which one? I can't see where you can simplify the fraction. In the second one it's 3(x^2)y + 4 (that's not a y)

Comment: At the bottom of the page .. $3x^2y^2+4y=y\cdot(3x^2y+4)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one take $-x$ common and then cancel to get$$\int -1/x dx=-\ln x=\ln x^{-1}$$ and hence the factor is $x^{-1}$ For the second take $y$ and do the same